# Removing shade from status bar in dialogfragment when using android:windowTranslucentStatus

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

So I want to be able to show fullscreen dialog with status bar on top of it (dialog itself being behind the status bar). But I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I cannot use

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Because it makes status bar dissapear completely.

If I try to use:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

I am able to go below status bar, but status bar is still grey (I believe it uses some level of transparency to darken the content behind)

This option doesn't work when combined with **android:windowTranslucentStatus**:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
```

Content doesn't go behind status bar if I use:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

My content goes behind navigation bar if I use this:

```
setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

So how do I achieve what I want?

Comment: Fullscreen dialog is not a good practice. You probably need to implement separated activity for your goals.

Comment: Why is it not a good practice?

Comment: because dialogs usually use to inform users about a task and can contain critical information, require decisions, or involve multiple tasks. But if you need a full screen dialog, check this link: https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#

Comment: Thanks for the link. I would use fragments, but Is it more appropriate to have one transparent fragment on top of the other?

Comment: No, it isn't. What is the main goal of your implementation? Maybe there are exists  more pretty solutions

Comment: I have to follow design made by some designer and it required me to show full screen dialog over existing fragment with parts of it being transparent. Including status bar and area below it.

Comment: Maybe attach the screen you want yo implement to your question?